# Request too large in jsp login page

Tags: java, jsp, performance-testing

I have developed a Dynamic web project in JSP and servlets and it works fine, but when I try to login to the system it says

> Request header is too large

Who can help me?

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720422/java-tomcat-request-header-

Comment: what is your form method? post or get? GET method have limitation for passing parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it my self! I was using HTTP GET instead of the HTTP POST. Technically I have seen HttpGet will have an issue if the URL length goes beyond 2000 characters. In that case, it's better to use HttpPost or split the URL. Browsers have limits ranging on the 2kb - 8kb