# Request header is too large Spring-MVC-Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring

When I post `xml` data in header it is saying Request header is too large. I tried all the solutions posted on Stackoverflow.

[Request header is too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472905/request-header-is-too-large)

[JAVA -tomcat- Request header is too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720422/java-tomcat-request-header-is-too-large)

I am using Spring-MVC-Ajax.

Below is the Ajax Call

```
$("#btnSubmitEdit").click(
                        function(event) {
                            $(document.body).css({"pointer-events": "none", "cursor": "wait"});
                            var reqMsgId = $("#msgID").val();
                            var reqMsg = $("#xmlMessage").val();
                            $.ajax({
                                        url : "update/" + reqMsgId,
                                        data:{reqMsg: encodeURIComponent(reqMsg)},
                                        type : "POST",
                                        success : function(data) {
                                            $(document.body).css({"pointer-events": "", "cursor": "default"});
                                        },
                                        error : function(e) {
                                            $(document.body).css({"pointer-events": "", "cursor": "default"});
                                            alert("Error" + e.responseText);
                                        }
                                    });
                        });
```

Here is spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{reqMsgId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updatePage(@PathVariable("reqMsgId") String reqMsgId, @RequestParam("reqMsg") String reqMsg) {
    System.out.println(reqMsg);
    esbresubmitmessageservice.updateMessage(reqMsg, Integer.parseInt(reqMsgId));
    return "success";
}
```

Getting following Error :

```
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:512)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:171)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:996)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Don't use this: `url : "update/" + reqMsgId + "?reqMsg=" + encodeURIComponent(reqMsg),`...use `url : "update/" + reqMsgId, data:{reqMsg: encodeURIComponent(reqMsg)}`

Comment: getting this error: WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Appname/403] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Comment: May be this is because of controller issue. Is that correct fiction to receive ajax post requests.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a controller issue...you can check the Network tab(f12) on your browser to check the url you are pointing and to see if is rightly formed.

Comment: getting same issue.

Comment: I forgot to mansion that I am running this in eclipse

Comment: Well, for this kind of projects, and when your level of expertise is like, junior level, I would recommend you to write a simple method on your server code, and an ajax call on your client side...start adding parameters on both sides, looking at the request on the network tab...and once everything works fine and you have a major understanding, then move to something more complex....

Comment: and why won't you use POST with xml body for your call?

Comment: I have update above with POST but failed to receive in controller.